# Google Cloud SQL[postgres] - db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I googled and changed my postgres password from command line, I can able to login through windows client with no issue, but when i checked the database log through stackdriver on google it shows that "password authentication failed", not sure that is happening same i have attached below.

[image]
Please let me know how to fix this on Google space.

Comment: We're going to need the code. Just the error and the log aren't going to be enough to help you. Unless your database isn't actually named `postgres` in which case, that's the problem.

Comment: I did not get it exactly. So you were able to connect without any issue, but the logs show you the contrary?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses but things worked out itself after some time, I am hoping that from Google side something went wrong as after some time the same code working fine, but again i did not know what was the issue behind the scene. I think we can close this issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Still not went into the root cause but after some time when i redeployed my code into google app engine it went fine. still not done from my side but no change done on the code so considering from google side something went wrong at Cloud SQL[postgres] instance which got disappear.

Thanks for all putting your effort on my question.